# using wcf or odata for data entry in wp7

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, odata, data-entry

Does anyone have a simple data entry example which involves WCF (Odata ) and WP7?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here are two good places to start:

- [Introduction to WCF Data service and
  ODATA](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/1619/)
- [OData and WCF Data
  Services](http://www.orbitone.com/en/blog/archive/2010/06/09/odata-and-wcf-data-services.aspx)

Once you have the service itself running, you would access it in the WP7 application the same way you access any other WCF service.

Note that there is a [OData Client Library for Windows Phone 7](http://www.odata.org/developers/odata-sdk). You might also want to read [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phaniraj/archive/2010/03/19/developing-a-windows-phone-7-application-that-consumes-odata.aspx) for some additional info.